# How to get Telegram List of users joining group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How can I get information from telegram about new users joining my group, I want it to record on a spreadsheet of the member name and who he/she invited into the group. Is there a way for me to do this?

I try to look at some Telegram API in https://core.telegram.org/bots/api but it didn't really help me at all.

Answer (score 1):

When a members joins a group, you'll receice a [`Message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) update, with `new_chat_members` set.
If you're using the `python-telegram-bot` library (which I assume, as you used the tag), you can filters for those updates by adding a [`MessageHandler(Filters.new_chat_members, ...)`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.new_chat_members).

Answer (score 1):

You can use message [Filters](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.new_chat_members) to trigger a function when a new user joins the group

**Example**

```
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters

def new_user(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("New user joined.")

def main():  
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
        MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, new_user)
    )
```

When a user joins the group this bot will leave a reply *"New user joined."*